# How to write logfile for nsca daemon

Tags: logfiles

I am using nsca daemon on a server which logs into /var/log/messages

I have not found out how to log into a specific file.

How to log nsca daemon into a logfile?

Comment: you want to store the logs generated by the daemon to a logfile other than syslog. Is this you want or what is your question.

Comment: yes - i want it to have the log output generated by daemon in a logfile and not in /var/log/messages

Comment: http://wpollock.com/AUnix2/Logging.htm